# How to add invisible items to ListView in C#?

Tags: listview

I'm going to develop a project which interacts with files and folders through a ListView control in the program's UI. I've added a custom sort method to the listview to sort items according to its different columns. There are some columns in the listview like Size and Date. Size column contains the shortened size value, e.g. "1.9 MB" instead of "2000000" bytes, so it's impossible to sort the listview items by the shortened size values and obtain the expected result.

Is there any way to add some invisible columns to the listview to store extra values in it? Or bind some extra items to listview items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes simple things become so complicated.
I've got it... An easy and handy solution...

Actually **it is possible** to have hidden items as easy as having more subitems than columns. E.g. having 6 subitems and 4 columns means that we have 2 "hidden" subitems. The only remaining thing is redirecting the sort procedure to these sortable hidden subitems (columns).

Thanks to **WraithNath** & **Robert Levy**...

Answer (score 1):

You cant have invisible columns but you could set the width of the columns you dont want to show to 0. This way they would not show up unless a user tried to resize the column next to it. Visually a user would now know its there

Comment: Be sure to override the resize events if you don't want them able to "find" your hidden column.

Comment: Thank you WraithNath, but I'm looking for some better solution. I've applied Vista theme to my listview and now the listview reveals its zero-width columns. ;)

Comment: Hi maxeemo, are you sorting the data based on the list items in the list view or at the datasource? You could perform the sorting directly in the source with some linq but then you would need to clear and refil the list due to the lack of datasource property. This would have a performance hit but that is a drawback for using a list view. I seem to remember seeing a databinding list view on code project that may be worth a look also.

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this problem without the hidden columns by customizing how sorting is done.

for winforms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter.aspx

for wpf:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription.aspx